# Can’t Delete CloudFormation Stack

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to learn how to deploy containers to AWS using [this tutorial](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/automated-software-delivery-using-docker-compose-and-amazon-ecs/):

I am trying to tear it all down and start again. But I am stuck on trying to delete 1 of the 3 stacks, ‘compose-application'. Its status is ROLLBACK_COMPLETE but I can’t delete it.

When I try to delete it using the delete button in the AWS portal (CloudFormation > Stacks) I just get an error ‘Failed to delete stack’.

The command line gives me:

```
> aws cloudformation delete-stack --stack-name compose-application
An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the DeleteStack operation: Role arn:aws:iam::<my account id>:role/compose-pipeline-ExtractBuildRole-13J3XICP8GXYL is invalid or cannot be assumed
```

But I am using my root user account, and I was able to delete my other stacks this way.

The rollback skipped deletion of the Redis EFS volume. I am not sure if that’s the issue. But I can’t find the volume in the EFS interface or anywhere.

How do I finish deleting this stack?

Answer (score 1):

It make take a little time to settle down on current state, try to log out and back into your account, retry stack deletion afterwards.
And open stack resources to find out what resource exactly it is failing to delete.

Comment: Thanks Eugene, I waited 3 hours and logged out and back in. Still can't delete the stack. The only remaining resource is RedisdataFilesystem, which is in the DELETE_SKIPPED state. Is it possible to delete is manually? I can't find it anywhere, I checked under EFS or MemoryDB

Comment: Actually the EFS volume has no physical id. Just a logical ID of 'RedisdataFilesystem' and a type of AWS::EFS::FileSystem.